# SMTP settings in appSettings.json in dotnet core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

In Asp.net, I can normally send emails using the following code:

```
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    await smtp.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
}
```

With the smtp settings being provided in the web.config, which are then automatically used by the `SmtpClient`. The web.config config section looks like:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
      <network host="myHost" port="25" userName="myUsername" password="myPassword" defaultCredentials="false" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Is it possible to have config in the appSettings.json file in a dotnet core 2.0 application, which can then be used by the `SmtpClient`, similar to Asp.net?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407221/startup-cs-in-a-self-hosted-net-core-console-application this should answer your question

Comment: First, don't use SmptClient. Second, there's no special meaning to any XML or JSON section with .NET Core. There's no special meaning to `appsettings.json` either, it's just the default file name used by WebHostBuilder.

Comment: So use what instead of `SmptClient`? And so you're saying I'll have to specify the smtp details manually?

Comment: To explain `don't use SmptClient.`, the class's documentation itself explains [it's obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2), only there for compatibility reasons *even in the Full Framework* and that you [should use `MailKit` instead](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md)

Comment: The *proper* way to use whatever SMTP service you want is to load its configuration from the .NET Configuration system, from whatever source you've configured. It could be a section named `"MyMailSettings"` in your `json` file. Second, you should *register* that class as a service, not instantiate it manually.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using DI to inject my email service. Thank you for your help, I'm going to go along with [this](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/02/using-mailkit-send-receive-email-asp-net-core/) example.

Comment: Check [Using MailKit To Send And Receive Email In ASP.net Core](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/02/using-mailkit-send-receive-email-asp-net-core/). It shows how you can load settings from JSON, how to create and register an `IEmailService`

Comment: Can I pass the SmtpClient via dependency injection rather than new'ing it up?

Comment: The above link is using mailkit but it still calls SmtpClient?

Answer (score 21):

If you insist on using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient, you can do it this way:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Smtp": {
    "Server": "mail.whatever.com",
    "Port": 25,
    "FromAddress": "yourfromemail@whatever.com"
  },
}
```

**Code:**

```
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = htmlMessage;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.To.Add(email);

        string host = _config.GetValue<string>("Smtp:Server", "defaultmailserver");
        int port = _config.GetValue<int>("Smtp:Port", 25);
        string fromAddress = _config.GetValue<string>("Smtp:FromAddress", "defaultfromaddress");

        message.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);

        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(host, port))
        {
            await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
        }
    }
```

Where `_config` is an implementation of `IConfiguration` which is injected into the class in which the `SendEmailAsync` method resides.

However, since it's obsolete, it might be better to explore other methods as mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: I don't want to manually get the smtp config values from appsettings.json though. I was asking whether the values can be used automatically.

Comment: Don't think that's possible.

Comment: It gives me this error "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Unauthenticated senders not allowed" @HaukurHaf

Comment: @NitikaChopra that means that the mail server you are using requires authentication.  You need to add support for username/passwords and then send that information into the SmtpClient class constructor along with the host and port.

Comment: @HaukurHaf thanks for reply. but actually my silly problem is that I entered the wrong username, I rectify this my problem is solved.. :)

Comment: Can I pass the SmtpClient via dependency injection rather than new'ing it up?

Comment: @variable I can't see why not ...

Comment: Ok so in that case am I correct to say that the injected SmtpClient and its parent service class (if any) must be both registered as transient or scoped and not singleton?

Comment: Regular DI lifetime restrictions/best practices should apply.  Sorry for the vague answer :)

Answer (score 9):

What you probably want to achieve is like this:

**File:** `appsettings.json` (where you define your data)

```json
{
    ...
    "EmailSettings": {
        "From": "no-reply@example.com",
        "Username": "username",
        "Password": "password",
        "Host": "smtp.example.com",
        "Port": 25
    },
    ...
}
```

**File:** `Email.cs` (where you define a model that will contain the data)

```cs
public class EmailSettings
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
}
```

**File:** `Startup.cs` (where you bind the data to the model that will be available everywhere)

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{              
   ...

     services.AddConfiguration<EmailSettings>(Configuration, "EmailSettings");

   ...
}
```

**File:** `Email.cs` (where you define how to send a mail)

```cs
public class EmailService
{
    private readonly EmailSettings _mailSettings;
    public EmailService(EmailSettings mailSettings)
    {
        _mailSettings = mailSettings;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SendMail(MailRequest mailRequest)
    {
        //Here goes your code to send a message using "_mailSettings" like:
        // _mailSettings.From
        // _mailSettings.Port
        //ect...
    }
}
```

To do so open [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/appsettings-6-ways-to-read-the-config-in-asp-net-core-3-0/) and go to Way 6 named "*#6 AppSettings – PRE-Binding*"

There your will find different ways to make this work but the 6th way is highly recommended

Comment: I took this answer and went further. Using the IOptions interface to implement Alex's suggestion inside a .Net Core 6 Program.cs.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0