# ASP.NET Core in a Worker Service doesn't call Configure IApplicationBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-service-worker

I was migrating an **ASP.NET Core App** to the Worker Service template and was intending to keep the `Startup` code.
However after

within **Program** I kept the **CreateHostBuilder** as described on the MS Docs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
            webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
        .ConfigureServices(
            services =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
```

while debugging, the `ConfigureServices` is being called

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

but the `Configure` within the Startup, is not reached / called

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
```

before it crashes calling `Run()`.

I also tried this with the same result:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.Configure(Startup.Configure))
        .ConfigureServices(
            services =>
            {
                Startup.ConfigureServices(services);
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
```

The interesseting part is that the following code actually calls the `Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)`:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.Configure(Startup.Configure));
```

As soon as I am adding `ConfigureServices` it skips the `IApplicationBuilder` configuration call.

Am I missing something or what is the suggested way to achieve this?

Edit:

the exact error is:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder' while attempting to
>   activate 'Kledex.Extensions.KledexAppBuilder'.

stack trace:

> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable'1
>   serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection
>   services, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection
>   containerBuilder)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter'1.CreateServiceProvider(Object
>   containerBuilder)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()

the error happens as soon as it reaches `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();` and tries to resolve the registered services, while the above one has a dependency to some config `app.UseSomething();` within the `Startup.Configure()` method.

A breakpoint in `Startup.Configure()` doesn't get hit.

Comment: Show the error message when it crashes. Usually the code within Startup is not executed until the first request comes in

Comment: I added the error details and such. The **Startup** is being executed as soon as the app runs, which of course makes sense, since the service registration within the **Startup** happens _before_ services and dependencies are requested. 
What you probably ment is the resolution of services and dependencies, which happen as soon as these are requested. In example Controllers and DI.

Nevertheless, the issue here is that `Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` is never called, even when requested.

Comment: I meant in a normal web app, Startup.Configure isn't called until the first request. Anyways your error message indicates that it's all failing prior to that point because it cannot create an instance of KledexAppBuilder which appears to have a dependency on IApplicationBuilder, the latter of which I am pretty positive doesn't get added directly  to the DI container (hence their method UseKledex... I think)

Comment: That is the case, however this works very well like this `public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().UseIISIntegration()`. As such there must be a difference in the lifecycle of the Builder or the way it needs to be configured.

Comment: I think it might depend on where you are trying to use the KledexAppBuilder. Is it in the worker service?

Comment: I don't care too much where it gets called, it basically can be called as soon as the service starts or the the first time requested. I have no problem moving it to the worker, but I only see the KledexAppBuilder as an extension call to `IApplicationBuilder` which I have no idea how to inject into the service worker. If you give me a hint, I will try it out.

Comment: No--I was thinking that if you were trying to inject it into the worker service that was probably the reason the DI was failing. Anyways--per the exception, *somewhere* `KledexAppBuilder` is being injected and cannot be constructed itself because an `IApplicationBuilder` isn't in the container. I would track down where it's being injected and see if you can backtrack. I know nothing about `Kledex` so I can only go by the exception's message

Comment: Have you found a solution here @RaulSebastian ?

Comment: @RaulSebastian any solution to this one?

Comment: @MoonKnight What ASP.NET Core version are you using?

Comment: Hi, for my particular case, I have managed to solve this after a long painful weekend. Mine was a threading issue...

Comment: @RaulSebastian Could you please share you `Startup` code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you are trying to configure web host defaults and use `ASP.NET Core` features like `IApplicationBuilder`, *I believe that you are planning to run the service over some kind of web server*. Is this correct?

If so, besides the other good suggestions, I have another one, which is to keep using an `ASP.NET Core` app - obviously enabling the usage of the `Startup` almost *as is* (with `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods) and perhaps most of your previous app.

To do so, in your `Worker csproj`, you could replace `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">` by `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`.

Then, you can configure your `CreateHostBuilder` such as:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
            webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Please note that I removed `UseWindowsService()` on purpose, since I am describing a case of using `Worker services` and not specifically `Windows services`.

Now you can keep using your `Startup` class, adding the registration of your background service(s):

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // ...
    }
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :) However, if you specifically want to develop `Windows services` rather than `Worker services`, please let us know.

In this case, **we keep having an ASP.NET Core WebApp/WebAPI** with all its capabilities. We just added background services to it :)

Comment: This seems like the best answer. I'm guessing, but if OP _really_ needs the IApplicationBuilder then they need a web service with a background scheduler, not a worker service with a kludged together startup.

Comment: Thank you :) Perhaps both options can solve more or less the same use cases, yes... I've seen some nice examples regarding the use of worker services, like web apps running in containers, with background workers performing async tasks like publishing events or getting information from other services/message brokers. This also allows the use of observability tools for the worker services, like Health endpoints and telemetry, as well as taking advantage of containers orchestration capabilities (e.g. in Kubernetes). This becomes quite useful when working with SOA and microservices :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's your problem:

You are trying to use a pattern that was specifically designed for ASP.NET Core, but you aren't using ASP.NET Core and because of that you aren't getting the `Startup` pattern or any of it's features such as `IApplicationBuilder` or `IWebHostEnvironment`.

A while back, someone asked if we could figure out how to get the `Startup` pattern of ASP.NET Core in to something that uses the generic host builder without the use of ASP.NET Core. [I came up with an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63603562/1204153).

The above answer doesn't give you the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` method, *and it shouldn't*. That method is *specifically for a Web Host*. Not a worker. **There is no reason you should need this method *unless* you are starting up a Web Host.**

And if that's the case, then you should start over and create a brand new ASP.NET Core application... Not a Worker. This will configure your application to use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK and not `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker` SDK giving you the features you lost by going the Worker route.

You will *not* get an answer that will work for you unless you move away from the Worker SDK and move to the ASP.NET Core SDK. Maybe someone will come up with something, but more than likely it will be a kludge. And kludges break overtime and are a PITA to maintain.

There is nothing wrong with using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` for a Windows service. Microsoft even [shows you how](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service) (Specifically pay attention to [Deployment Type section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#deployment-type)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I had the same issue.

Answer for the question we can find in the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#app-configuration).

We need to use method `ConfigureAppConfiguration` for Host Services.

Please review my code examples. We use this code and it works fine:

---

**Program.cs**:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
            {
                var environment = context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
                builder.AddAppSettings(environment);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

---

**HostedService**

```
public class HostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<HostedService> _logger;

    public HostedService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, ILogger<HostedService> logger)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Service is starting...");

        // Run new task and use your business logic
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            // Resolve business manager class with many dependencies. It is Scoped LifeTime.
            var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IClientManager>();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Service is stopping...");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

[image]

---

So we had only one trouble with this approach, we can inject only singletons to `HostedService` class. We will inject `IServiceScopeFactory` to constructor. And after it we create scope, resolve all needed dependencies and run our business logic.

Answer (score -3):

You can move configuring of your HostedService from Program class to Startup. Just add this to ConfigureServices method before calling AddControllers:

```
services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

I'm including HostedService in my project in this way and it works.

That's my standart CreateHostBuilder:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Comment: did you read the sample code above? That is exactly what I did, but the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` is not being called at runtime.