# How to setup the DI container in a .NET Core console app?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I created a new .NET Core console app and installed the following packages

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.Options
- Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions

I created a appsettings.json file for the configuration

```
{
  "app": {
    "foo": "bar" 
  }
}
```

and I want to map those values to a class

```
internal class AppOptions
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I also want to validate the options during configuration so I added a validating class

```
internal class AppOptionsValidator : IValidateOptions<AppOptions>
{
    public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, AppOptions options)
    {
        IList<string> validationFailures = new List<string>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Foo))
            validationFailures.Add("Foo is required.");

        return validationFailures.Any()
        ? ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(validationFailures)
        : ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I want to setup the DI container and created a testing scenario

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConfigureServices();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices()
    {
        IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        // Setup configuration service

        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(configuration);

        // Setup options

        IConfiguration configurationFromDI = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>(); // This is just for testing purposes

        IConfigurationSection myConfigurationSection = configurationFromDI.GetSection("app");

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<AppOptions>, AppOptionsValidator>();
        serviceCollection.Configure<AppOptions>(myConfigurationSection);

        // Try to read the current options

        IOptions<AppOptions> appOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<AppOptions>>();

        Console.WriteLine(appOptions.Value.Foo);
    }
```

Unfortunately the variable `configurationFromDI` is null. So the variable `configuration` wasn't added to the DI container.

How do I setup the Dependency Injection for console applications correctly?

Comment: Put `serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();` after your add

Comment: There's no need to write all of this code though. Since you use so many extensions already, it's better (and easier) to use HostBuilder, the same way an ASP.NET Core application does and use its `ConfigureServices`, `ConfigureAppConfiguration` methods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Startup.cs in a self-hosted .NET Core Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407221/startup-cs-in-a-self-hosted-net-core-console-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call to `BuildServiceProvider` should be made *after* all services are registered.

There's no need to write all of this code though. Since you use so many extensions already, it's better (and easier) to use [the generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host), the same way an ASP.NET Core application does and use its `ConfigureServices`, `ConfigureAppConfiguration` methods:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configuration =>
            {
                configuration....;
            });
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                var myConfigurationSection = configuration.GetSection("app");

                services.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<AppOptions>, AppOptionsValidator>();
                services.Configure<AppOptions>(myConfigurationSection);

            });
}
```

Configuration is available through the [HostBuilderContext.Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuildercontext.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) property.

[CreateDefaultBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) sets the current folder, configures environment variables and the use of `appsettings.json` files so there's no need to add them explicitly.

**Appsettings.json copy settings**

In a web app template, `appsettings.json` files are added automatically with the `Build Action` property set to `Content` and the `Copy to Output` action to `Copy if Newer`.

There are no such files in a Console app. When a new `appsettings.json` file is added by hand, its `Build Action` is `None` and `Copy` to `Never`. When the application is debugged the current directory is `bin\Debug`. With the default settings, `appsettings.json` won't be copied to `bin/Debug`

`Build Action` will have to change to `Content` and `Copy` should be set to `Copy if Newer` or `Copy Always`.

Comment: thanks! :) I tried out your code example https://pastebin.com/bDvh9vuK but unfortunately it's not able to read from the appsettings.json file. I always get options validation failures. Do you know what's missing? What needs to be in `ConfigureHostConfiguration`?

Comment: Nothing's missing. I use this in a dozen CLI tools, so it's not just code copied from the docs. Is `appsettings.json` copied to the output folder? When you add a new JSON file its `Build Action` is `None` and the `Copy` setting is set to `Never`. When you debug your application the current directory is `bin/Debug` so your app won't see any `json` files there. You need to set `Copy` to `Always` or `Copy if newer`. You need to set the `Build Action` to `Content` to have the file included during publishing or packaging

Comment: ah didn't know that :) Since there is nothing to do in `ConfigureAppConfiguration` and `ConfigureHostConfiguration` I removed them. The code still seems to work fine. Would you mind having a look at the updated version? https://pastebin.com/VYsfSbEe

Answer (score 1):

**DI in Console project**

You can setup DI in any executable .net-core app and configure services in a Startup class (just like web projects) by extending `IHostBuilder`:

```
public static class HostBuilderExtensions
{
    private const string ConfigureServicesMethodName = "ConfigureServices";

    public static IHostBuilder UseStartup<TStartup>(
        this IHostBuilder hostBuilder) where TStartup : class
    {
        hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((ctx, serviceCollection) =>
        {
            var cfgServicesMethod = typeof(TStartup).GetMethod(
                ConfigureServicesMethodName, new Type[] { typeof(IServiceCollection) });

            var hasConfigCtor = typeof(TStartup).GetConstructor(
                new Type[] { typeof(IConfiguration) }) != null;

            var startUpObj = hasConfigCtor ?
                (TStartup)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TStartup), ctx.Configuration) :
                (TStartup)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TStartup), null);

            cfgServicesMethod?.Invoke(startUpObj, new object[] { serviceCollection });
        });

        return hostBuilder;
    }
}
```

Now, you have an extension method `UseStartup<>()` that can be called in `Program.cs` (the last line):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // for console app
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); 
      
        // For winforms app (commented)
        // Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
        // Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        // Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        // var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        // Application.Run(host.Services.GetRequiredService<MainForm>());
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                // any other configurations
            })
            .UseStartup<MyStartup>();
}
```

Finally, Add your own `Startup class` (here, `MyStartup.cs`), and inject `IConfiguration` from constructor:

```
public class MyStartup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // services.AddBlahBlahBlah()
    }
}
```

P.S: you get `null` because you call `.BuildServiceProvider` before registering IConfiguration

**Mapping appsettings.json**

For mapping `appsettings.json` values to a type, define an empty interface like `IConfigSection` (just for generic constraints reason):

```
public interface IConfigSection
{
}
```

Then, extend `IConfiguration` interface like follow:

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static TConfig GetConfigSection<TConfig>(this IConfiguration configuration) where TConfig : IConfigSection, new()
    {
        var instance = new TConfig();
        var typeName = typeof(TConfig).Name;
        configuration.GetSection(typeName).Bind(instance);

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Extension methdod `GetConfigSection<>()` do the mapping for you. Just define your `config classes` that implement `IConfigSection`:

```
public class AppConfigSection : IConfigSection
{
    public bool IsLocal { get; set; }
    public bool UseSqliteForLocal { get; set; }
    public bool UseSqliteForServer { get; set; }
}
```

Below is how your `appsettings.json` should look like (class name and property names should `match`):

```
{

.......

"AppConfigSection": {
    "IsLocal": false,
    "UseSqliteForServer": false,
    "UseSqliteForLocal": false
  },

.....

}
```

And finally, `retrieve` your settings and map them to your `ConfigSections` as follow:

```
// configuration is the injected IConfiguration
AppConfigSection appConfig = configuration.GetConfigSection<AppConfigSection>();
```

Comment: I think where you have (inside Program.cs):
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
you meant:
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration((config) =>

Comment: @RobbSadler depends on framework, .net-core or dotnet