# Dependency Injection in a Console App using c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have come into an already-written app that uses Dependency Injection and I've successfully added to one of the existing projects in the solution, now trying to add a NEW project and can't really seem to get things figured out.

Because it's a CONSOLE app and not an MVC app, I'm really thrown with how to setup the `Program.cs` to work.

Basically, I need to know how to use the `ProjectSearchManager` (via `IProjectSearchManager`) from a console app.

These are the relevant (I think) sections of my `Startup.cs`...

```
public class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataConnection")));

            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            ConfigureRepositories(services);
            ConfigureManagers(services);
           
        }

        private static void ConfigureRepositories(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IAdoRepository, AdoRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<ProjectSearchResults>, Repository<ProjectSearchResults>>();
        }

        private static void ConfigureManagers(IServiceCollection service)
        {
            service.AddScoped<IProjectSearchManager, ProjectSearchManager>();
        }

    }
```

What is the syntax that works to do something similar in `Program.cs`?

Currently I have this...

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureRepositories(services);
            ConfigureManagers(services);

            // NOW I WANT TO RUN METHODS INSIDE ProjectSearchManager...
            // HOW?

        }
        
        public static void ConfigureRepositories(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IAdoRepository, AdoRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<ProjectSearchManager>, Repository<ProjectSearchManager>>();
        }
        public static void ConfigureManagers(IServiceCollection service)
        {
            service.AddScoped<IProjectSearchManager, ProjectSearchManager>();
        }
    }
```

And the code seems to run but I can't access the methods inside `ProjectSearchManager`... I can't figure out what I'm missing or where I'm going wrong.

This may be very basic dependency injection stuff, I don't know. I was able to get it to work in MVC easily but in the console app, seems like the setup is more challenging or something.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

UPDATE...

I reviewed the post at --> [How to run .NET Core Console app using generic host builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392429/how-to-run-net-core-console-app-using-generic-host-builder)

I tried updating the code to read as such...

```
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices(services => { services.AddScoped<ProjectSearchManager>(); })
                .Build();

            var my = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ProjectSearchManager>();
            my.SearchAsync();
```

I get the following error...
Unable to resolve service for type 'Solution.DataLayer.Abstracts.IRepository`1[Solution.DataLayer.Entities.ProjectSearchResults]' while attempting to activate 'Solution.Managers.ProjectSearchManager'.

Comment: You need to use `IHost`, which handles the `ServiceCollection` and service container for you. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392429/how-to-run-net-core-console-app-using-generic-host-builder

Comment: That error *should* be plainly obvious to you what it means. It's telling you that you haven't registered something to resolve the dependency on IRepository<ProjectSearchResults> that ProjectSearchManager class depends on. It's that easy. All you need to do is add something to the service collection to resolve that dependency, just like you did with `services.AddScoped<IRepository<ProjectSearchManager>, Repository<ProjectSearchManager>>();`

Comment: @mason -- i hear u. i'm sure it's simple but i have been staring at this for a week and having trouble with what i'm sure is an easy solution. i can't seem to figure out what the `something` part is...

Comment: Look at what you did for the `Repository<ProjectSearchManager>`. Now find the equivalent class for `Repository<ProjectSearchResults>`. Rinse, wash, repeat. Do you understand what that services.AddScoped method call does? Why it's necessary?

Comment: and if i update that, i now get... `No service for type 'Solution.Managers.ProjectSearchManager' has been registered.`

Comment: Your code directly depends on ProjectSearchManager? However, you haven't registered anything to resolve a dependency on ProjectSearchManager, only on IProjectSearchManager. Therefore, you must either change how you register that dependency (not recommended) or instead start depending on IIProjectSearchManager. Change `var my = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ProjectSearchManager>();` to `var my = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IProjectSearchManager>();` You may then run into an error because you registered it as a Scoped, but you're not in a scope where you're trying to resolve it.

Comment: Probably all your AddScoped calls should be AddTransient.